# Where is the body of the textio package?

Tags: vhdl, textio

I have used the textio package several times and thought about reading it. When I opened the textio package from my ModelSim library window in the std library I found that the body of the package is not in the textio.vhdl file. Thus, I can onyl see the declaration of the functions in the file but not their body.

How/Where can I find all contents of the textio package i.e its body?

Comment: One common characteristic of packages in library STD is that they are only defined to provide declarations. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.4 Package TEXTIO, 16.3 Package STANDARD (which can't be analyzed), and 16.5 Standard environment package (STD.ENV). Also see 13.2 Design libraries (these are the only packages in STD). They form an abstraction layer between a design specification and the tool implementation for things that can't be written in VHDL or aren't accessible, dealing with host file or text I/O and simulator structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no VHDL implementation. Instead, the implementation of the textio package is simulator specific. Think of it as "implemented in C" rather than implemented in VHDL.